# how to implement this new operation with recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

I have a homework that include a new operation (a [n] b), given:

- a [1] b = a<sup>b</sup>
- a [n] 1 = a
- 2 [2] 3 = 2 [2-1] (2 [2-1] 2) `2 repeated 3 times` = 2 [1] (2 [1] 2)  =  2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup> = 16
- 2 [2] 2 = 2 [2-1] 2 `2 repeated 2 times` = 2 [1] 2  =  (2<sup>2</sup>) = 4
- 4 [3] 3 = 4 [3-1] (4 [3-1] 4) = 4 [2] (4 [2] 4) `4 repeated 3 times` = 4 [2] (4 [1] (4 [1] ( 4 [1] 4))) =
  = 4 [2] 4 <sup>4<sup>4<sup>4</sup></sup></sup>

I don't need a solution, I just need advice so that I can solve it myself.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve the formatting.

Comment: You cant overload operators in C.

Comment: Are you trying say you want to implement a recursive function that raises a number to an integer power?

Comment: No it's just a new operation that I should write a recursive function for, not a power function.

Comment: @RedX I'm not trying to overload anything in C

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth it's the best that I can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is being said here can be rephrased as follows.

> For any positive integers a, b and n define

```
    a [n] b = a [n-1] ( a [n-1] ( ... a ) ) taken b times
```

In a C-like language

```
int myoperator (a, n, b) {
    int x, i;
    x = a;
    if (n == 1){
       x = pow(a,b);
    } else {
       for(i = 1; i < b; i++){
           x = myoperator (a, [n-1], x);
       }
    return x;
}
```

Note that the values will grow quickly and get out of the range of machine integers very soon.

Note also that `a[n]b` can be defined as

```
 a [n] b = a [n-1] ( a [n-1] (b-1) ).
```

using this definition the `for` loop above can be eliminated.

```
int myoperator (a, n, b) 
int a,n,b;
{
    int x;
    x = a;
    if (n == 1) 
        x = pow(a,b);
    else if (b == 1) 
                x = a;
         else {
              assert(b>1 && n>1);
              x = myoperator (a, n-1, myoperator(a,n-1,b-1));
         }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but your solution including 'for' statement is there a way to do it without 'for' !?

Comment: @Rawhi yes, it is possible to replace `for` with a recursive call.